# FindParent in WPF CustomControl return null

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a circular slider (a customcontrol) to select HUE of a color. I'm facing this problem when running my demo app. FindParent, "_templateCanvas" in this case, is always null but can't find out why.

Here is part of the HueWheel class :

```
public class HueWheel : Slider
{
    static HueWheel()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HueWheel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HueWheel)));
    }
    private bool _isPressed = false;
    private Canvas _templateCanvas = null;

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = false;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isPressed)
        {
            if (_templateCanvas == null)
            {
                _templateCanvas = MyHelper.FindParent<Canvas>(e.Source as Ellipse);
                if (_templateCanvas == null) return;
            }

            const double RADIUS = 150;
            Point newPos = e.GetPosition(_templateCanvas);
            double angle = MyHelper.GetAngleR(newPos, RADIUS);
            //huewheel.Value = (huewheel.Maximum - huewheel.Minimum) * angle / (2 * Math.PI);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class to find the parent :

```
public static class MyHelper
{
    public static T FindParent<T>(FrameworkElement current) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
            do
            {
                current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current) as FrameworkElement;
                if (current is T)
                {
                    return (T)current;
                }
            }
            while (current != null);
            return null;
    }
```

Here is what I have in Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HueWheel}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HueWheel}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Slider Name="huewheel">
                        <Slider.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Viewbox>
                                    <Canvas Width="300" Height="300">
                                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Assets/HueCircle.PNG" Focusable="False" Height="300" Width="300" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                                </TransformGroup>
                                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" Width="300" Height="300" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"/>
                                        <Canvas>
                                            <Line Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="5" X1="150" Y1="150" X2="150" Y2="0"/>
                                            <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="140" Canvas.Top="30"/>
                                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                                <RotateTransform CenterX="150" CenterY="150">
                                                    <RotateTransform.Angle>
                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueAngleConverter}">
                                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value"/>
                                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Minimum"/>
                                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Maximum"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </RotateTransform.Angle>
                                                </RotateTransform>
                                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        </Canvas>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Viewbox>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Slider.Template>
                    </Slider>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The canvas exist in the xaml, the ellipse I'm mouving the mouse on is contained in this canvas, so I should be able to get the ellipse parent (the canvas).

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: In your code you've commented out the event handlers. Is this what you're testing, because as it stands none of your code will be executed.

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner, which event handlers are you talking about ? sorry it's that a dumb question

Comment: <!-- MouseLeftButtonUp="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Ellipse_MouseMove"/>--> etc.

Comment: ah yes, they are not needed, this is a port from usercontrol, but in customcontrol they are defined inside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, "What's the Matter with Canvas?"

I tried testing your code, and I wasn't surprised to find that `e.Source` was of type `HueWheel`, which inherits from `Slider` and not from `Ellipse`. For that reason, this expression always returns `null`:

```
e.Source as Ellipse
```

...therefore, a) `e.Source` is not the object you thought it was, and b) this next statement always sets `_templateCanvas` to `null`:

```
_templateCanvas = MyHelper.FindParent<Canvas>(e.Source as Ellipse);
```

`FindParent` returns `null` immediately because you always pass it a `null` for the `current` parameter. Neither canvas is a *parent* of the `HueWheel` anyhow (which you knew -- what you didn't know was that `e.Source` *was* the `HueWheel` -- but the first thing you'll know to do next time is slap in a breakpoint and hover the mouse over `e.Source` to see what you've got).

So now let's fix it. What follows is **How You Do It In WPF**, pretty much, except for whatever details the real smart guys hassle me about in comments.

I don't know which Canvas you're trying to grab here, so I'll grab you both of them. First, give them `x:Name` properties in the template; I'll call them `PART_FirstCanvas` and `PART_SecondCanvas` because I didn't figure out the semantics. I've also rewritten your template to eliminate the inner slider; I don't understand why you put a retemplated slider in a template for a slider. The trouble there is that I was unable to call the inner slider's `GetTemplateChild()` method, because it's protected. My other option was to write a minimal subclass of `Slider` which merely exposes `GetTemplateChild()` publically, and use that for the inner slider. If there's a good reason to have two sliders which wasn't obvious to me (maybe one's an X coordinate and the other's Y?), we can update this to do it that way.

```
<ControlTemplate 
    TargetType="{x:Type test:HueWheel}"
    >
    <Border 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        >
        <Viewbox>
            <Canvas 
                Width="300" 
                Height="300"
                x:Name="PART_FirstCanvas"
                >
                <Image 
                    Stretch="Fill" 
                    Source="Assets/HueCircle.PNG"
                    Focusable="False" 
                    Height="300" 
                    Width="300" 
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                    >
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
                <Ellipse 
                    Fill="Transparent" 
                    Width="300" 
                    Height="300" 
                    Canvas.Left="0" 
                    Canvas.Top="0"/>
                <Canvas
                    x:Name="PART_SecondCanvas">
                    <Line Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="5" X1="150" Y1="150" X2="150" Y2="0"/>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="140" Canvas.Top="30"/>
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform CenterX="150" CenterY="150">
                            <RotateTransform.Angle>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueAngleConverter}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value"/>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Minimum"/>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Maximum"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </RotateTransform.Angle>
                        </RotateTransform>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                </Canvas>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Next, we'll add private members for those two named Canvases, and grab them in an override of `OnApplyTemplate()`. Then we'll use whichever we want in that mousemove event:

```
public class HueWheel : Slider
{
    static HueWheel()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HueWheel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HueWheel)));
    }

    private bool _isPressed = false;
    private Canvas _PART_FirstCanvas;
    private Canvas _PART_SecondCanvas;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        //  Use () cast rather than the "as" operator because if the actual runtime 
        //  type can't be cast to the desired type, that'll throw an exception 
        //  rather than silently returning null. If you had cast (Ellipse)e.Source, 
        //  that would have blown up on you because you can't cast HueWheel to Ellipse. 
        //  That would have instantly shown you what was wrong. 
        //  But you won't get an exception here if GetTemplateChild() just returns null. 
        _PART_FirstCanvas = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("PART_FirstCanvas");
        _PART_SecondCanvas = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("PART_SecondCanvas");
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isPressed)
        {
            const double RADIUS = 150;

            //  Or _PART_SecondCanvas; whichever. 
            Point newPos = e.GetPosition(_PART_FirstCanvas);

            double angle = MyHelper.GetAngleR(newPos, RADIUS);
            //huewheel.Value = (huewheel.Maximum - huewheel.Minimum) * angle / (2 * Math.PI);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = false;
    }
}
```